# programmatically changing meta description in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have a meta description tag in page and I am changing the meta description tag's content programmatically like this

```
 <meta name="description" content=<%=getmeta()%>  />
```

the getmeta function like following

```
   public string getmeta()
{
    return "this is a meta description's content";

}
```

when my page renders it renders senseless meta element like this

```
<meta name="description" content="this" is="" a="" meta="" description's="" content="" >
```

What is the cause of this, what am I missing?

Comment: Did it really compiled? You have extra ")" at the end of return statement in getmeta function.

Comment: Everything is down-voted here! Even the correct answers!! : )

Comment: @DaveBecker Which answers are correct?

Comment: I am also concatenating Request.Cookie value. Now it's giving me content="this is a meta description's content" edmonton,alberta"=". I am concatenating like this +HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["pc"].Value).ToString().Replace(" ","")

Comment: Just use your original code but replace the `content=<%=getmeta()%>` with `content="<%=getmeta()%>"` (note the extra double quotes)

Comment: @DavidG now it's rendering this:content="<%=getmeta()%>"

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your code does not compile, because you have an extra ')' at the end in your method:

```
return "this is a meta description's content");
```

But, to answer your question, the content for the meta-tag should be placed between double quotes in order to work.

I do suggest that you adapt your method to return a string with double quotes included, but this would require to escape your double quoted characters.

If your modify your method like the following it should work (tested & verified):

```
public string getmeta()
{
    return "\"this is a meta description's content\"";
}
```

The output in the HTML would then be:

```
<meta name="description" content="this is a meta description's content"  />
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the double quotes in the markup instead of messing around with strings?

Comment: That's just my personal way of working. I don't really like that so therefore I'll add them in the string itself.

Answer (score -1):

**Best approach is**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<meta name='description' content='this is a meta description's content'  />"));
}
```

**OR another way is-**

-Put `PlaceHoled` in your .aspx `header` section.

`<asp:PlaceHolder id="MetaPlaceHolder" runat="server" />`

C# code :

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "Name1";
meta.Content = "this is a meta description's content";
MetaPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Comment: Please adding a comment if you think this eligible for `downvote`

Comment: Well for a start it doesn't fix the problem and your "best" approach contains errors.